# Flutter DropdownButtonFormField icon doesn't align properly

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Good morning, I am trying to align the DropDown's arrow icon with the hint text but I can't understand why the render engine positions it so far below.

I tried to set the InputDecoration's `contentPadding` property to `EdgeInsets.zero` and it seemed to work. However, it ruined the DropDown's focusBorder. Furthermore, I didn't understand what element the padding is attached to.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Example> createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.black87,
        ),
      ),
      width: 135.0,
      height: 55.0,
      child: _buildField(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildField() {
    return DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
      icon: const Icon(
        Icons.expand_more,
        size: 30.0,
        color: Color(0xFF2E2E2E),
      ),
      hint: const Text(
        'Status',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 18.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          color: Color(0xFFA6A6A6),
        ),
      ),
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            width: 2.5,
          ),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Color(0xFFFF7321),
            width: 2.5,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      items: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4']
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
            (String item) => DropdownMenuItem(
              value: item,
              child: Text(item),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
      onChanged: (String? value) => print(value),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DropdownButton is a material component as seen on [material.io](https://material.io/components/menus#exposed-dropdown-menu).
This means that Flutter has every single styling hard-coded into the default styling like its defined on this website. It appears that by forcing this widget into a certain height:

```dart
return SizedBox(
      height: 55.0,
      child: Stack(...
```

you break the prebuilt styling of this widget. I have tested it with a height 50 to demonstrate this:
[image: Broken Dropdown Menu]

Here, you can see why setting the height is a bad idea on a Material Component.

Enough talking, what is the solution: Remove the height from SizedBox and any styling that is given by the material component:

```dart
return DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
      icon: const Icon(
        Icons.expand_more,
        //size: 30.0,
        color: Color(0xFF2E2E2E),
      ),
      hint: const Text(
        'Status',
        style: TextStyle(
          //fontSize: 18.0,
          //fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          color: Color(0xFFA6A6A6),
        ),
      ),
```

Now I know this will break your UI, but this is how Flutter works. Either you completely adopt the Material Design, or you will have a really bad time.

Comment: Good morning, thank you for the insight. So are you telling me Material Components can only be styled with texts and colors but not with properties that affect size? I thought the component would have resized itself to fit its parent's available space.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example code I wrote for you.

My code:

```
        DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            ),
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.expand_circle_down, // Custom icon goes here.
            ),
            iconSize: 30, // Icon height goes here.
            hint: const Text('Choose item'),
            value: _dropDownValue,
            items: _dropDownList
                .map(
                  (label) => DropdownMenuItem(
                value: label,
                child: Text(
                  label.toString(),
                ),
              ),
            )
                .toList(),
            onChanged: (value) {
              _dropDownValue = (value ?? _dropDownList[0]);
              setState(() {});
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Good morning, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it didn't solve the issue. It seems to be something related to predefined sizes of the DropdownButtonFormField that can't resize themselves based on their parent.